# Reference books for Homolology and Cohomology using Algebraic approach.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation

I am a newcomer for Homology. I want to study homology and cohomology for research purpose, using the algebraic approach. I was studying the research paper Homology of multiplicative Lie rings(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404906000533) but not able to understand a few things. There are some questions for the same but they are using the concept of simplicial complexes and other topological approaches([Approach to Learning Co/Homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143738/approach-to-learning-co-homology)). Kindly give some references so I can learn Homology using groups and modules.

Comment: Look for texts on "homological algebra".

Comment: Sir, there are so many books on the internet. Which should I prefer? I want to make you sure that I don't know more about this.

Comment: Weibel's book on homological algebra is nice

Comment: Ok thanks, sir. I will try to go for this book.